# ngx-bootstrap modal clickable focus element outside the modal

Tags: ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-modal

I need to focus an element even the ngx-bootstrap is already shown.

Hi All,

I am currently using ngx-bootstrap modal.

Here is what i want to achieve.

1.ngx-modal is already show with some data --working

2.Now, what i want to happen is that, i need to click an element outside
of the modal, but currently it's not happening due to modal-container is blocking.
Is there a way to focus an element outside of my modal even though the modal is shown.
I've already eveything ,ignoreBackDrop and backdrop settings, it's still not working

tia.

Answer (score 0):

I've already fixed the issue by setting the zIndex on the parent element (not the modal) greater than modal z-index value